# how to consume json object in a servlet that has been passed in the ajax request

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jquery, servlets

I have the below ajax call to a servlet.

```
$.ajax({ 
type: "post",
url: registersubmit.RegisterServlet.json,
dataType: "json",   
data:$('#registrationForm').serialize(),          
success: function(msg) {  
           //   alert(msg.data);
           alert('success'+msg.message2);     
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
         alert('HAI');
         alert('BYE');
}  
});
```

May I know how we can consume the json object in the servlet

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a huge misunderstanding here. The way how you sent the ajax request doesn't end up in a JSON object in the server side at all. All the data is just available by `request.getParameter()` the usual way. The [`$.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) merely collects all input values of the form into a JSON object which is in turn behind the scenes by `$.ajax` encoded as HTTP query string the usual way. The JSON object is merely an intermediary format which allows you to very easily submit the *entire* form using `$.ajax`.

So, the data of

```html
<form id="registrationForm" ...>
    <input name="foo" ... />
    <input name="bar" ... />
    <input name="baz" ... />
</form>
```

can in the servlet just be collcted exactly the same way as if it were a synchronous (a regular) submit

```
String foo = request.getParameter("foo");
String bar = request.getParameter("bar");
String baz = request.getParameter("baz");
// ...
```

Please note that the `dataType` option instructs the jQuery `$.ajax()` as which data type the **response** should be treated. It has totally no relationship with how the data is been sent by the request. It's just been sent as HTTP request parameters *the usual way*. See also [`$.ajax()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

#### See also:

- [Simple calculator with JSP/Servlet and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114742/simple-calculator-in-jsp)
- [Ajax program form username validation in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500184/ajax-program-form-username-validation-in-java)
- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GSON library](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) a Java library that can be used to convert JSON representation
into Java objects and vice versa

Comment: Whilst this does indeed answer OP's concrete question as stated in the title, this does not solve OP's concrete problem as shown in the code snippet at all.